# Google dataflow created via google cloud deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to create a dataflow job with template Pub/Sub to BigQuery via deployment manager.
The problem is that I don't  see any dataflow service after running `gcloud deployment-manager types list` command.

Is it possible to have an yaml file to create dataflow job?

Comment: Can you please include a code block with the redacted contents of your deployment config, or a link to the template that I assume you found online somewhere? It will help us figure out where you're trying to plug in the "dataflow" service - it's possible that you need something other than "dataflow" in that spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to provide you with a working sample of how to setup Dataflow for Cloud Deployment Manager, based on the answer from @lukaszberwid.

First you need an `options.yaml` file, to setup the [auth](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/type-providers/creating-type-provider#authentication) (additionally you may need to setup your service account within your env):

```
options:
  inputMappings:
  - fieldName: Authorization
    location: HEADER
    value: '$.concat("Bearer ", $.googleOauth2AccessToken())'
```

Then, to register dataflow run:

```
gcloud beta deployment-manager type-providers create dataflow \
    --descriptor-url='https://dataflow.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1b3' \
    --api-options-file=options.yaml
```

Next you can find a sample `resources.yaml` that can launch the `WordCount` template from the get started [guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#wordcount):

```
resources:
  - name: "datafow-job"
    type: "[PROJECT-ID]/dataflow:dataflow.projects.locations.templates.launch"
    properties:
      projectId: [PROJECT-ID]
      location: us-central1
      gcsPath: "gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/latest/Word_Count"
      jobName: testing-job
      environment:
        bypassTempDirValidation: false
        tempLocation: "gs://[BUCKET-NAME]/dataflow/tmp"
        ipConfiguration: "WORKER_IP_UNSPECIFIED"
        additionalExperiments: []
      parameters:
        inputFile: "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt"
        output: "gs://[BUCKET-NAME]/dataflow/output/my_output"
```

To run it:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create my-deployment \
    --config resources.yaml
```

Comment: That's awesome! Any idea how to stop or cancel a job? If I try to delete the deployment, it actually tries to launch the template as a new job. I belive you can achieve this with the REST API by updating the job's requestedState to JOB_STATE_CANCELLED, but seems like deployment manager doesn't know how to do that when calling ´deployments delete my-deployment´

Answer (score 3):

If you have a RESTful CRUD API with OpenAPI specification, it can be used as a type provider. [docs](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/type-providers/creating-type-provider)

Dataflow provider is not registered by default and you'll have to register that yourself. [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/)

To register dataflow run:

```
gcloud deployment-manager type-providers create dataflow 
 --descriptor-url='https://dataflow.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1b3'
```

you can see all the types avaiable for dataflow with:

```
gcloud deployment-manager types list --provider dataflow
```

Comment: Thx for that anwser, you know the complete schema to create dataflow with google cloud deployment manager ?

Comment: let me look around, but I'm not an expert on dataflow API

Comment: @Mihenandi-fukiWony I've tried to make some adjustments as an edit within this answer, on how to setup Dataflow for Cloud Deployment Manager and a sample YAML to launch a Dataflow job. However, it was rejected so I'm going to write it down as a new answer.